# KeyError: 'TensorArrayV3' in Object detection

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

Following is the part of my code . I am running a code already developed and getting some errors on tensorflow framework

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef() 
with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read() 
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph) 
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
```

And the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 55, in <module>
tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='') 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 258, in 
import_graph_def
op_def = op_dict[node.op]
KeyError: 'TensorArrayV3'
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message suggests that the `GraphDef` you are importing was created with a *newer* version of TensorFlow than the version you are currently running. The `TensorArrayV3` op was added to TensorFlow in [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/029539120a186073506a09983c72e7b4dc24ee74), which should be available in all versions of TensorFlow since version 1.0.0. This suggests that you are running a version of TensorFlow that is earlier than 1.0.0, and you should upgrade to a later version.